# How can I write a recursive function having $\Theta(n^7)$?

Tags: algorithms, recursion, recursive-algorithms

How can I write a recursive function having $\Theta(n^7)$ cost?
I must only use if, then, else statements and a function called $G(n)$ that costs $\Theta(n)$.

For example:

```
funz(n) {
if(n <= 1) 
  return 0;
else {
  G(n);
  return funz(n-1);
}
```

This has a cost of $\Theta(n^2)$. I must write something similar but having $\Theta(n^7)$ cost.

Obviously I can't modify G(n) function.

Comment: One could easily use G(n) as G(n*n) and obtain $O(n^2)$ complexity I guess, and similarly reach $O(n^7)$, and then putting it inside the recursive function.

Comment: @gunes I edited to better explain my problem, thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you familiar with the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) for recurrence relations?

Comment: Yes I'm familiar with master theorem. It would be simple to solve the problem using many nested for cicles but I can't use for cicle. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following algorithm has a Big-O complexity of $O(n^7)$:

```
fn(n) {
    if (n < 0)
        return 0;
    else {
        G(n*n*n*n*n*n);
        return fn(n-1);
    }
}
```

The number of steps of this algorithm will be:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n i^6 = \cfrac{1}{42} n (n + 1) (2 n + 1) (3 n^4 + 6 n^3 - 3 n + 1) = \cfrac{1}{42} (6n^7 + 21n^6 + 21n^5 - 7n^3 + n)
$$
So its Big-O complexity is $O(n^7)$.

Comment: I wonder if this can be intended, since then one could equally well just do `G(n*n*n*n*n*n*n)` once and for all.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you